# How to make PHP call directory listings from a password protected directory

Tags: php

I am a web developer currently making a site.
For this site, I need to have a PHP script show the directory listings from a password protected directory. I am kinda new to PHP so any help at all would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a class, that can read a directory tree and return files that contain [Password Protection](http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/password-protection/)

```
<?php

class PasswordProtectedDirectoryReader
{

    protected $directory = false;
    private $expected_access_contents = array();
    protected $directoryinfo = array();
    protected $passworddirectories = array();
    protected $directorytree = array();
    protected $treeReady = false;

    public function __construct($directory)
    {
        $expected_access_contents   = array();
        $expected_access_contents[] = "AuthType";
        $expected_access_contents[] = "AuthName";
        $expected_access_contents[] = "AuthUserFile";

        $this->expected_access_contents = $expected_access_contents;

        if (!file_exists($directory)) {
            trigger_error("directory ({$directory}) can not be found");
            return false;
        } else if (!is_dir($directory)) {
            trigger_error("directory ({$directory}) is not a folder!");
            return false;
        }

        // Get Info about the Tree Origin
        $this->directory     = realpath($directory);
        $this->directoryinfo = pathinfo($this->directory);

        // Draw the Directory Tree
        $this->directorytree = $this->_get_folder_tree($this->directory, false);
        $this->treeReady     = TRUE;

    }

    protected function _get_folder_tree($directory_path, $directory_tree)
    {

        if ($this->treeReady) {
            trigger_error("The directory tree has already been drawn");
            return $this->directorytree;
        }

        $directory_instance            = array();
        $directory_instance            = array_merge($directory_instance, pathinfo($directory_path));
        $directory_instance['path']    = $directory_path;
        $directory_instance['subdirs'] = array();

        $directory_file_glob = glob("{$directory_path}/.*");
        $directory_file_glob = (array) $directory_file_glob;

        $htaccess_password_files = array();
        if ($directory_file_glob && !empty($directory_file_glob)) {
            foreach ($directory_file_glob as $file_item) {
                if (!is_file($file_item)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $file_contents = file_get_contents($file_item);
                $file_result   = true;
                foreach ($this->expected_access_contents as $expectedValue) {
                    $file_result = ($file_result && strstr($file_contents, $expectedValue));
                }
                if ($file_result) {
                    $htaccess_password_files[] = $file_item;
                }
            }
        }

        $scandir_results = array_filter(glob("{$directory_path}/*"), 'is_dir');
        $scandir_results = (array) $scandir_results;

        $subtree_results = array();
        foreach ($scandir_results as $subkey => $subfolder) {

            if ($subfolder === '.') {
                continue;
            } elseif ($subfolder === str_repeat('.', 2)) {
                continue;
            }

            $subfolder_path = $subfolder;
            $subfolder_path = (string) $subfolder_path;

            $subtree_result = $this->_get_folder_tree($subfolder_path, $directory_tree);
            $subtree_result = (array) $subtree_result;

            if ($subtree_result && !empty($subtree_result)) {
                $subtree_results = array_merge($subtree_results, $subtree_result);
            }

        }

        if ($subtree_results && !empty($subtree_results)) {
            $directory_instance['subdirs'] = array_filter($subtree_results);
        }

        if (($htaccess_password_files && !empty($htaccess_password_files))) {
            $directory_tree[]            = $directory_instance;
            $this->passworddirectories[] = $directory_instance;
        } else if ($directory_instance['subdirs'] && !empty($directory_instance['subdirs'])) {
            $directory_tree[] = $directory_instance;
        }

        return $directory_tree;

    }

    public function get_tree()
    {
        return $this->directorytree;
    }

    public function get_pwd_tree()
    {
        return $this->passworddirectories;
    }
}

?>
```

Usage

```
<?php

require_once "PasswordProtectedDirectoryReader.class.php";
$password = new PasswordProtectedDirectoryReader('directory_parent/');

echo "get_pwd_tree";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($password->get_pwd_tree());
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Output

```
get_pwd_tree
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [dirname] => F:\xampp\htdocs\PasswordProtectedDirectoryReader\directory_parent
            [basename] => password_directory
            [filename] => password_directory
            [path] => F:\xampp\htdocs\PasswordProtectedDirectoryReader\directory_parent/password_directory
            [subdirs] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Folder Structure

```
+---child_directory
\---password_directory
    |   .htaccess
    |
    +---directory_child_one
    |   \---directory_child_two
    |       \---directory_child_three
    \---second_directory
```